# Can I change the style/format of Laravel's Artisan-generated files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I run `php artisan make:controller UserController --resource`, Laravel (5.5) will generate a controller for me with some pre-populated functions (`index`, `show`, `store`, etc.). This obviously extremely handy, however it does generate these functions with a specific style:

```
function index()
{
    //
}
```

Is it possible to change it, so that instead it generates functions like this?

```
function index() {
    //
}
```

This would be to get the generated code to conform to our coding style guide.

This is admittedly an incredibly minor thing, and it's certainly not *that* much of an issue to just correct the brackets manually, but it would be great if there were a way to get Laravel to do this automatically. It would be *even better* if such a functionality could be built as a package that we could just require on other Laravel projects, though I'm not entirely sure how one would do that - so I'll just start with 'is this even possible?'

Comment: That's because it's formatted as PSR-4 I believe, or at least PSR-2.  There are template files hidden somewhere that are read out and filled with that data. Check out the other question how to work around it.